# Cannot convert single json object received from server to required type so can dissect the data

Tags: arrays, json, angular, variable-assignment, angular16

I apologize in advance if i am asking too stupid questions but i am really new to angular and i do not understand how to handle a JSON object coming from the server and convert that object into a custom datatype so i can use that data to render on html using ngFor.

I have tried multiple things but nothing seems to work. Any help will be very much appreciated.

P.S. please excuse me for the extremely simple html page, application is coming up from scratch and i am working on functionalities and backend server connections before working on the designs.

Below is the Code and screenshots attached.

```
Employee.Component.html
<div>
    <br>
    <h2>Employee Data</h2>
    <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <th *ngFor="let column of columns">
        {{column}}
      </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let row of empById; index as i">
        <td *ngFor="let column of columns; index as j">
          {{row[column]}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

```
employee.component.ts file:
 columns = [
    'employeeId',
    'firstName',
    'lastName',
    'address',
    'project',
    'ssn',
    'joinDate',
    'status',
  ];
 
  empById: any;
  empId: any;
 constructor(private testService: TestService) {}
  ngOnInit() {}
public getEmployeesById() {
    console.log('get Details for id: ' + this.empId);
    this.testService.getEmployeeById(this.empId).subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        this.empById = data;
        console.log('Response: ' + this.empById);
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching employees: ', error);
      },
    });
  }
```

```
EmployeeService file:
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeServiceService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getEmployeeById(empId:number): Observable<GetEmployee[]>{
    console.log("Inside get Employees By Method.");
    return this.http.get<GetEmployee[]>("https://localhost:9090/employee/getEmployeeById/"+empId,{responseType:'text' as 'json'});
  }
  }
```

```
GetEmployee class type:

export class GetEmployee{
    employeeId:any
firstName: any;
    lastName: any;
    address:any;
    project:any
    ssn:any;
    joinDate:any;
    status:any

        constructor(
employeeId:number
            firstName: string,
            lastName: string,
            address:string,
            project:string,
            ssn:number,
            joinDate:Date,
            status:number
        ){}
    }
```

I wanted to convert the JSON data coming from the server to GetEmployee type and then run a ngFor loop in the html so i can put everything in the tabular format.

But angular keeps on complaining that the data i am getting is in Object Format and ngFor can only be used on observables and iterators. Below is the image attached of how the object gets pulled from server and when i click on getAllEmployees button, it just renders the object itself. I am not able to print the data if i dont call {{ employees }} directly.

[image: Error I am getting instead of creating GETEMPLOYEE in correct format]

[image: When i try the same code in StackBlitz]

When i try the same code in stackBlitz, i am able to see it just fine. But my local browser keeps on giving me this issue. I am thinking it has something to do with the ngfor loop that i am trying to run in html, but i dont know any other way to solve this issue as i am very new to angular.

Answer (score 0):

In `employee.component.ts` please set the initialization to `{}`

```
empById: any = {};
empId: any = {};
```

> initially these values are undefined, so when you try to access the property of an undefined value you get this error, hence if we define the value to `{}` until the proper value gets set, you will not get this error!